# Golang: ListenUDP / ListenPacket not working on specific IP/Interface on Linux

Tags: go, bind, ethernet, dhcp

I programmed a DHCP-Server in Go and I'm using net.ListenPacket but also tried net.ListenUDP on a specific interface.
Background: A PC can have multiple Network interfaces, when a dhcp request arrives the dhcp-offer has to be send over the same interface where it came from. But on Linux (AlmaLinux 8.6) I even didn't get the DHCP-Request. In netstat I see that the Port 67 is bound to the wanted IP. If I use "net.ListenPacket("udp4", ":67") I receive the request but the dhcp-offer is send through the wrong interface.

The specific initialisation for the listender looks like this:

```
func ListenAndServeIf(handler dhcp.Handler, ifIP net.IP) error {
    l, err := net.ListenPacket("udp4", net.JoinHostPort(ifIP.To4().String(),"67"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer l.Close()
    return dhcp.Serve(l, handler)
}
```

Under Windows it works just fine.
Same with ListenUDP

```
func ListenAndServeIf(handler dhcp.Handler, ifIP net.IP) error {
    udpAddr := net.UDPAddr {
        Port: 67,
        IP: ifIP,
    }
    net.ListenUDP("udp4", &udpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer l.Close()
    return dhcp.Serve(l, handler)
}
```

According to the documentation it should work

```
// ListenPacket announces on the local network address.
//
// The network must be "udp", "udp4", "udp6", "unixgram", or an IP
// transport. The IP transports are "ip", "ip4", or "ip6" followed by
// a colon and a literal protocol number or a protocol name, as in
// "ip:1" or "ip:icmp".
//
// For UDP and IP networks, if the host in the address parameter is
// empty or a literal unspecified IP address, ListenPacket listens on
// all available IP addresses of the local system except multicast IP
// addresses.
// To only use IPv4, use network "udp4" or "ip4:proto".
// The address can use a host name, but this is not recommended,
// because it will create a listener for at most one of the host's IP
// addresses.
// If the port in the address parameter is empty or "0", as in
// "127.0.0.1:" or "[::1]:0", a port number is automatically chosen.
// The LocalAddr method of PacketConn can be used to discover the
// chosen port.
//
// See func Dial for a description of the network and address
// parameters.
//
// ListenPacket uses context.Background internally; to specify the context, use
// ListenConfig.ListenPacket.
```

And

```
// ListenUDP acts like ListenPacket for UDP networks.
//
// The network must be a UDP network name; see func Dial for details.
//
// If the IP field of laddr is nil or an unspecified IP address,
// ListenUDP listens on all available IP addresses of the local system
// except multicast IP addresses.
// If the Port field of laddr is 0, a port number is automatically
// chosen.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: on Linux the outgoing interface is a routing decision, and not determined by IP